# MD5 Duplicate Entries mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm having a bit of a problem when it comes to a single mySQL script; specifically, mySQL keeps giving me this error:

`MySQL Error: Duplicate entry '39835a3f63f222c9bf51d9dd471b90bc' for key 'PRIMARY'`

It's pretty weird cause the primary key in question is a MD5 generated hash based off of the time() function of php, so there shouldn't be any issues.

This is the php code that inserts into the table:

```
INSERT INTO log
    (hailID, timestamp, lat, lng, phone, device, method, serviceType, email, address, languageID, ipaddress)
        VALUES
    (MD5('" . $time . $data['phone'] . "'),
     '$time',
     '".$data['lat']."',
     '".$data['lng']."',
     '".$data['phone']."',
     '".$data['device']."',
     '".$data['method']."',
     '".$data['serviceType']."',
     '".$data['email']."',
     '".$data['address']."',
     '".$data['languageID']."',
     '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."'
```

`$time` in this case, is just a variable holding the value from the `time()` function. Funnily enough, this problem isn't very frequent, and it appears to be random (at least as far as I can tell). And yes, all the data is sanitized using `mysqli_escape_string()` before it goes into the `$data` array. I've also checked my table using `CHECK TABLE` and no errors have appeared either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If someone hits the submit button twice in very rapid succession, this will happen.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your `$time` variable looks like? If it isn't unique (ie. doesn't give the full date/time), then you would get collisions every 12/24 hours.

Comment: why generate your own id, when you could just have mysql do it via auto_increment, and guarantee uniqueness? an unsigned bigint gives you 2^64 ids to boot.

Comment: Any reason you're using the escape function instead of simply using [proper SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to do the job for you?

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions; looks like I'll be auto-incrementing the IDs from now on! and @tadman, no specific reason for using the escape function, although placeholders do seem to be a better idea!

Comment: Placeholders are a *way* better idea. A statement with them is generally not vulnerable to SQL injection bugs. A statement like yours, well, it depends on how perfectly careful you are which is always a bad thing. Dangerous by default is never good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 2 entries are logged within the same second they will have the same hash value. This will happen more frequently than you think on even a fairly low-use system. I would suggest:

1. Do away with the hash. Store the current time as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` using `NOW()`. You'll actually have a sortable table.
2. Use a surrogate key in the log file, ie an `INT` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`
3. If you need to store an exact, unique time and avoid duplicates look into PHP's [`microtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function.

Think about it, even if you stored the ID as an 8-byte `BIGINT` it's still 4x smaller than the `VARCHAR(32)` that you need to store an MD5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can sometimes run into a situation when the MD5 hash will be the same twice. Especially if (in your case) sb adds the same phone number twice in a second - the generated hash value will be certainly the same. Why don't you use auto increment primary key?